# How can I re-write this method using fetch?

Tags: axios, fetch, mern

In my react app i'm using axios for requests to the server.

```
  // This method will get the data from the database.
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/record")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ records: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

How can I re-write this method using fetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/record')
  .then(response => {
        this.setState({ records: response.data });
      })
  .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });;
```

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) if you want to use other request methods.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Now to re-write the other requests...